# How to toggle the auto-hiding of the taskbar in Cinnamon?

Tags: cinnamon

I'm looking for a way to quickly toggle the autohide of the taskbar in Cinnamon (running on a netbook).

Would it be possible to do it either directly using a shortcut, or maybe scripting and then keybinding it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copy and paste following script in gedit:

```
#!/bin/bash
state=$(gsettings get org.cinnamon panels-autohide)
if [[ $state = "['1:true', '2:false']" ]]; then
    gsettings set org.cinnamon panels-autohide "['1:false', '2:true']"
else
    gsettings set org.cinnamon panels-autohide "['1:true', '2:false']"
fi
```

... and save as `panel-autohide.sh` in your home directory.

Then open `System Settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboard shortcuts -> Custom shortcuts`.

Click on `Add custom shortcut`. Fill the Name section with `Toggle Panel Autohide`. In Command section, browse and select `panel-autohide.sh`.

Under "Keyboard bindings" double click on unassigned, and press keyboard shortcut for this command. I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> as keyboard shortcut.

Comment: exactly was I was looking for :)

Comment: actually this doesn't work in the latest cinnamon, so I suggest to use 'Intelligently hide panel' option.

Comment: my problem hear is that it needs to be executed as system user even when I execute the script as system user

Answer (score 3):

I use Cinnamon 2.0 and it has this feature by default.

**System Settings -> Panel** (for some reason I have 2 version of System settings in my App launcher. I used the first one to get the Advanced Mode)

[image: System Settings]

Check **Auto-hide panel**

[image]

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

you can look at this page https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/1754
see the comments given by askun

> Just in case you weren't aware, you can toggle the system tray
>   completely off in Cinnamon Settings > Applets. This doesn't offer the
>   more finite control over individual applications like you are
>   requesting, though, just "all on" or "all off" as far as I can tell...
>
> [image]

Comment: please dont make your answer only based on a link. do your best writing the key points and only then use the link as reference. if the link ever gets broken, so does your whole answer.